# Call the function only once when opening

Tags: java, android

Need your help!
How do I in my application to call the function only once when opening?
**I do:**

```
private boolean is_first = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if ( is_first ) {

        MyFirstFunction();   

    }    

}

public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onResume();
    is_first = false;
}
```

Also in the manifest file added to the activity `android:configChanges="orientation"` but still function when you turn the device restarts

I hope for your help!

Comment: Do you want to call it once total, or once everytime your app starts?

Comment: I need to run every time the application is started.

Comment: take a look at this: http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/10/27/handling-orientation-change-in-android.aspx

Comment: You need to change your Conception, create a singleton class and put your MyFirstFunction(); in the Constructor of your singleton, and destroy it within the onDestroy() of your Activity. Override on Orientation Change, to prevent activity from restart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use Application class to do that in the `onCreate` method you can call your function

```
public class MyApp extends Application {



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //this will be called each time you open the application 
        super.onCreate();
//call you function here 

    }   
}
```

then add this class to the manifest

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApp or your class name" 
......
....>
```

Comment: Yes, the function is called once, but how to work in this class with the elements or functions are triggered in the activity.

Comment: can you describe exactly what you want please

Comment: For example, how do set adapter for ListView located in MAIN activity?

Comment: in the onCreate I use AsyncTask android-query to get the json compare all this with the database if there are changes that ranks ListView Is it wrong? )))

Comment: Yes! (I had to immediately ask a question that way :))))